# Проблемы с отрисовкой UI

Tags: android, оптимизация, ui

Добрый день!

Столкнулся с такой проблемой:
У нас в проекте есть фрагмент,  на котором большое количество UI элементов (2 viewpager,  collapsing toolbar,  много editText). Из-за этого при смене на этот фрагмент не воспроизводится анимация и смена фрагмента выглядит держать.

Для оптимизации хочу сделать,  чтобы сначала загружался каркас фрагмента с анимацией без viewpagerов,  а после этого загружались остальные элементы. 
Есть ли возможность отследить событие,  когда фрагмент отрисовался?

Comment: На данный момент пробовал postDelayed,  но к сожалению я не могу наверняка знать за какое время отрисуется каркас фрагмента

Comment: Перенести загрузку остальных элементов в onResume() не пробовали?